# 3D Drawing using Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, drawing, mesh

I want to make a 3D painter using MATLAB.

First of all I want to display 3 panels - `XY`, `XZ` and `YZ` views.

The user will paint what he wants in each panel.

After that he will click on a button to combine the 3 views and get a 3d model from these panel. He also can render this model freely.

How can I do that?

These pictures illustrate what I want:

**2D Views :**
[image: 2D views]

**3D Object** after combining 3 views :
[image: 3D object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you only want to specify 3D lines and no solid blocks (as in the linked example). There I see a small problem: after specifying the XY and XZ projections, you have a x, y and z value for each point on the curve, so the YZ projection is already defined. It is therefore enough to specify only the XY and XZ dimension. Here's how to do that:

To get a graphical input from the user, you can use the `ginput` function, which creates a figure and allows the user to select points:

```
[x,y,btn] = ginput(k);
```

where `x` and `y` are the coordinates of the selected points, `btn` the ASCII code of any clicked button, and `k` is the number of points to get. You can let the user draw something and let the drawing end by pressing the space bar by:

```
figure; axis([0 1 0 1]);              % create empty figure
button=0; k=1;                        % set start values
while button~=' '                     % repeat until space is pressed
    [x(k) y(k), button] = ginput(1);  % get one point
    k=k+1;                            % set k for next iteration
    plot(x,y);axis([0 1 0 1]);        % plot the curve
end
```

You can repeat that twice to get the XY and XZ view. Let's assume you save the coordinates into the variables

```
(x1, y1)    % the XY view
(x2, z2)    % the XZ view
```

Now you can create the resulting 3D curve by creating an `x` vector and interpolating all `y` and `z` values. For a nice smooth curve I'd recommend the Spline interpolation:

```
x = 0:0.01:1;
y = interp1(x1,y1,x,'spline','extrap');    % Spline interpolation + extrapolation
z = interp1(x2,z2,x,'spline','extrap');    % Spline interpolation + extrapolation
```

Now just plot it in 3D with the `plot3` function:

```
plot3(x,y,z);
```

You can easily expand this minimal example to do whatever you need, this is just to show the basic steps and possibilities in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a complete answer, but this can be added with [hbaderts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4221706/hbaderts) answer

To generate a smooth [Spline](http://in.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/examples/constructing-spline-curves-in-2d-and-3d.html) **while drawing**, instead of straight lines (as he proposed)

```
figure; axis([0 1 0 1]);                    % create empty figure
button=0; k=1;
while button~=' '                           % repeat until space is pressed
    [x(k) y(k), button] = ginput(1);        % get one point                            
    plot(x(k),y(k),'r.');axis([0 1 0 1]);   % plot the points
    hold on
    fnplt(cscvn(vertcat(x,y)),'b',2);       % Generate smooth spline
    hold off
    k=k+1;                                  % set k for next iteration
end
```

**Before smoothing**

[image: hbaderts image]

**After Smoothing:**

[image: smoothed curve]